# Adding domain to Office 365 managed by google apps

Tags: dns, domain, office365, google-workspace

I want to add a new domain to Office365 but my domain was bought via google apps. Now I am having trouble verifying that I own this domain for one of the steps in Office 365. I have searched for answers and have seen some suggested solution that to access the Advanced DNS Settings from google apps. While I can access the DNS settings, the new TXT record which I added still does not allow me to be verified by Office 365. Can someone help?

Microsoft 365 instructed me to add the following:

TXT name: www

TXT value: MS=ms90643988

TTL: 3600

Anyone here who can help? Thanks

KM

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft will read that entry - which proves you had the authority to add it and hopefully means you own it.

Based on above your TXT record looks wrong.

When you add the TXT record to the domain you usually designate the host as "@" or "none" depending on the provider (not sure what Google Apps DNS looks like).   So my record appears like this:

[image]

After you added it do a lookup on it to make sure you it's in correctly (this can take upwards of 24 hours to replicate thru DNS servers).  You can use MX toolbox.  Put in your domain and it will show all your TXT records:
http://mxtoolbox.com/TXTLookup.aspx

Once you can see the record in MXToolbox you should be able to validate it whit Office 365